# NodeJS - Child Process - Exec VS Powershell ISE | why are the results different?? why can't the PSCredential be created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code, child-process

MY PS Script:

```
$admin = "TEST"
$Password =  ConvertTo-SecureString "Test12345" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = [PSCredential]::new( $admin, $Password)
if ($Credential -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]) {
return "PS Credentials - true"
} else {
return "PS Credentials - false"
}
```

RESULT in PS ISE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amyMw.png)

MY NODE JS Script:

```
"use strict";
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec(
    "powershell.exe -File C:\\Users\\fschiller\\Desktop\\Projekt_Node\\Libary\\TEST.ps1",
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(stdout)
    }
)
```

RESULT in VSCode from Node Script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWEjl.png)

I Dont know how to Fix it. Can Someone Help ? or know the Problem and how to work around it?

tried ExecFile,
other ways to creat PSCredential Object,
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]

Comment: Something clearly goes wrong with the creation of the credential object - maybe add `console.log(stderr)` to the callback?

Comment: Stimmt danke dir, VSCode hat scheinbar ein Problem beim erstellen eines SecureString  ConvertTo-SecureString : Der Befehl "ConvertTo-SecureString" wurde im Modul "Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" gefunden, das Modul 
konnte aber nicht geladen werden.  : $Password =  ConvertTo-SecureString "Test12345" -AsPlainText -Force
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertTo-SecureString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Comment: Alright, does it work if you explicitly call `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` at the top of the powershell script?

Comment: Leider nicht, Zählt auf welche Elemente schon vorhanden sind und schmeißt den fehler im Anschluss : + Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: It works if I specify the modul to the complete path  - Import-Module -Name "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.psd1"

Answer (score 1):

It works if I specify the module to the full path -

```
Import-Module -Name “C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.psd1"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just a band-aid, as you may run into trouble with other modules too. A robust solution requires (temporarily) undefining the `PSModulePath` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** isn't specific to any particular PowerShell host program (console vs. ISE vs. integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code), it **comes down to *indirectly* launching [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI *from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)***:

- This causes Windows PowerShell to inherit an **inappropriate `PSModulePath` environment-variable value** (`$env:PSModulePath`), with entries that pertain to PowerShell 7+ only, which **results in attempts to load *incompatible modules*** - which is what you saw.
- It is only if you call `powershell.exe` *directly* from PowerShell 7+ that the latter anticipates the problem and itself applies the solution described below.

Specifically, the **symptoms** with respect to the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` module that contains the `ConvertTo-SecureString` cmdlet in your case are:

- The first time you call `ConvertTo-SecureString` in a given session, its module is [auto-loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-autoloading) - but because an attempt is made to load the *incompatible* PowerShell 7+ version of the module, auto-loading fails with the following error:

  ```
  ConvertTo-SecureString : The 'ConvertTo-SecureString' command was found in the module 
  'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security', but the module could not be loaded.
  For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'.
  At line:1 char:1
  + ConvertTo-SecureString -?
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertTo-SecureString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
  ```
- Running `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` then yields the following error - its technical details aren't important, and unfortunately, it doesn't provide much of a clue as to what the problem is:

  ```
  Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: 
  Error in TypeData "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": The member AuditToString is already present.
  # ... (similar lines omitted)
  At line:1 char:1
  + Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
  ```

---

The **solution**, per a comment from a PowerShell team member in [GitHub issue #18530](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18530#issuecomment-1325691850), is to ***undefine* the `PSModulePath` environment variable** for the child process that indirectly calls `powershell.exe`:

Note:

- `delete`, as shown below, must be used to *undefine* (remove) a variable from `process.env` - *assigning* `''` (or `null` or `undefined`) to `process.env.PSModulePath` does *not* work.
- So as not to modify the *caller's* environment, a *copy* of the `process.env` is created, from which the variable is then removed, and passed via the `env:` property of an object as the `options` argument to
  [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)
- A simplified call to `powershell.exe` is used below, which simply prints the value of `$env:PSModulePath` as seen by the child process, which should then contain only the usual, Windows PowerShell-only entries.

```js
"use strict"
const { exec } = require("child_process")

// Create a copy of the current environment block
// and remove the 'PSModulePath' variable from it.
const customEnv = Object.assign({}, process.env)
delete customEnv.PSModulePath

exec(
    "powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command $env:PSModulePath",
    { env: customEnv }, // Pass the modified environment.
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(stdout)
      console.error(stderr)
    }
)
```